# I am a newbie (male), and want to get pump some mass to my butt, thighs and legs (they are very thin as compared to my upper body)

Tags: exercise, muscle, legs, muscle-mass, muscle-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chicken legs + butt exercises - video training without equipment (at home) OR WITH equipment?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/chicken-legs-butt-exercises-video-training-without-equipment-at-home-or-wi)

I am a newbie (male), and want to get pump some mass to my butt, thighs and legs (they are very thin as compared to my upper body)

I want to understand, what are the major areas to TARGET in each region:

1. Butt
2. Thighs
3. Legs

in order to gain mass and muscles?

I have no knowledge in body building whatsoever, nor I have knowledge about the popular terms.

Comment: Instead of re-asking the question under the same name but under different accounts, please register a profile and wait for answers.

Comment: @Informaficker   Here, I have asked for major regions to target. How it is a duplicate?

Comment: What do you mean by areas? Please try to be more precise about what you want to achieve. And please register with this site. It would make a lot of things easier for you (and me a bit happier).

Comment: And you are right, this isn't exactly a duplicate but in the current form I would also vote _not a real question_. All your questions basically target a leg problem, but all of them are unspecific in a way that they cannot receive good answers. If you would put a bit more time in forming one thorough question it would be far better for you and all the people with answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if anilkumble has no knowledge of the terms or physiology of what he is asking it will be hard for him to make a well thought out question.  So instead of belittling him we should hep him figure out what he wants to know.

Anilkumble, You asked what major areas you need to target (Butt, Thighs, and Legs) in each region. Did you mean exercises?  You have four major muscle groups in your legs.  Your butt (glutes), the front of your thighs (quadriceps), the back of your thighs (hamstrings), and back of your legs belos the knees (calf muscles).  There are also supporting muscle groups on the front of your hip (hip flexors), inside (addductors), outside (abductors), and beside your shin (anterior tibialis).

I hope this helps you make a more concise question.

Comment: Thank you. May, I also ask how to examine the progress of all of the areas?

Comment: The only real way to examine progress is to look at strength gains in those individual muscles.  You would need to know specific exercises for each of the muscles groups to test this though.

Comment: I have no intention to belittle someone, but we should uphold certain standards on this site. Anilkumble789 shows no intention of using the site  correctly (he did not register an account for any of his 4 other questions). I am happy to edit a question if I can make it more clear. For example if he registered an account with the site it would be possible to help him in [chat] instead of figuring out what he means in comments.